# Can DynamoDB primary key be a combination of keys with different data types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a DynamoDB table by importing DynamoDB JSON from S3.
The primary key is a combination of partition key(state_name) and sort key(trail_id).

Data types of keys are as follows:

- Partition Key: String
- Sort Key: Number

When I create table with such schema I get below error:

```
"One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key trail_id expected: S actual: N"
```

Why can't the primary key be formed with the combination of keys that are of different data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key can most definitely use a mixture of data types. The error states that you created the table with the sort key `trail_id` as a String (S), where in fact the data type is a number (N).

Be sure when your create the table you define `trail_id` as a Number (N).

Comment: Oh you are right! I miss understood the error and oversaw the option to mention data type for the keys while importing from S3. Changed type to Number and import is successful. Thank You.